# How to increment the total depending on the original number

Tags: java, android, numbers

Curious to pick people's brain. I'm looking at basically incrementing a total number based on the number I get from a server. I.e. say if I have `50/100` then when I get to a 100 it will change to `100/200`

I can't think for the life of me on how to implement this in a clean way so wanted to pick the communities mind on it.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: you mean to say you have no idea how to multiply by 2?

Comment: Are there any particular rules about what you'd increment the denominator by?

Comment: @adickinson not really. Stultuske... OMG I didn't think it through properly.

Comment: @BilalMH We can't really help you unless you provide us with requirements for the problem you want to solve, so go and have a ponder on that for a bit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multiply each number by two and you'll be able to accomplish your task.